# jQuery AJAX Post Int Array to MVC Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

This works in my development environment, and my staging environment but not the production environment.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Cancel(int[] id)
{
    // Code
}
```

My javascript

```
var contracts = [100, 200, 300];

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Contracts/Cancel",
                beforeSend: showLoader,
                complete: hideLoader,
                data: { id: contracts },
                traditional: true,
                success: handler.callback
            });
```

As I said, works fine in staging and dev but in production int[] id is null. Staging and Production are the same server just different virtual hosts. Is there some sort of configuration in IIS or is there something wrong with my code?

So currently if I need to cancel something that is in production i have to change the connection strings in dev to point to the production database and then cancel the items. So, it tells me that it's most likely a server related issue but no idea what it could be.

Comment: var contracts = [100, 200, 300]; this looks like a hardcoded values are you sure this is present

Comment: That is there to simplify the example. The actual code calls a function that returns an array.

Comment: are the ids null on the controller action "Cancel" or they are null on the contracts? the only time I had these was when I didn't have a model binder

Comment: It is the ids that are null.

Comment: shouldn't that be contracts.serialize(); Can you check using firebugs if you are actually sending something to the controller action Cancel, the values are normally visible on the POST of the console